# Automatic hyperlinking in Excel

Tags: excel

I am generating a csv file which has the link to specific files. It looks like:

D:\abc,D:\xxx..
D:\fgt\a.txt, D:\yxz..
.
.

Now when opening this in excel I want to make these get converted into hyperlinks so that the user clicks them and the corresponding file or folder opens up. 
Is there any way I can make the excel identify it as links and make them clickable links. A simple one or two steps in excel which would do this?

Thanks...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `HYPERLINK()` worksheet function in Excel. If your generated links are in column A, insert a new column (column B) and place the following formula in cell B1:

```
=HYPERLINK(A1)
```

Then simply fill down that formula in column B.

Comment: Woot for using the program's built-in functionality rather than writing code!

Comment: Hey Manoj, click the checkmark so eJames gets the credit he's due...  That's a small part of the system that keeps Stack Overflow working as great as it does!