# Hyperlink in Excel from csv both in english and french

Tags: r, excel, csv

I'm building a table in R which I save in a `csv` file.  That table is made for some user that will actually open it with `Excel`.  That table have a field with an hyperlink.  I want Excel to detect the link and allow the user to click on it directly to open it in their browser.  That is normally pretty easy, [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233519/automatic-hyperlinking-in-excel) explains you just have to add `'=HYPERLINK('` before your string.  This however doesn't work in all languages.  Excel as the weird behaviour of coding differently in French or English.  In my case, the users can have both French or English Excel making this solution not working.

Here is a reproductive example:

```
# prepare the data
field1 <- 1:4
link <- c("www.google.com", "www.duckduckgo.com", "www.yahoo.com", "www.altavista.com")

# English solution
dd_en <- data.frame(field1, link = paste0('=HYPERLINK("', link, '")'))
write.table(dd_en, "Y:/temp/tb_link_en.csv", quote=F, sep=";", col.names = T, row.names = F)
```

If I open in a French Excel, I get:
[image]

```
# french solution
dd_fr <- data.frame(field1, link = paste0('=LIEN_HYPERTEXTE("', link, '")'))
write.table(dd_fr, "Y:/temp/tb_link_fr.csv", quote=F, sep=";", col.names = T, row.names = F)
```

This time, in a french Excel I get:
[image]

Is there a way to have a universal solution?

Comment: Any interest in using an Excel *VBA* approach??

Comment: Not really, I'm a R coder, I haven't touch VBA in ages and the whole script for building the table is done, this is the only thing left to fix...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Universal solution 1 - build two csv files - one for French version, one for English. Then it will be ok.
- Universal solution 2 - build one csv file only in one language. Open the file in Excel, supporting this language. Then send the **Excel file** (not the CSV) to the people, using the other language. It will work, because Excel will take care of translating the formulas to the local language.

Comment: Solution 1 isn't a solution...  However, solution 2 is more promising.  I tried it and it works.  It requires one more step and software switching which sucks but at least it works.  I would have hope for some kind of generic function that is ALWAYS detected by excel as an hyperlink... I'm trying to save directly the table in an excel file to save the extra step but it isn't working so far...  I'll investigate more.

Comment: @Bastien - actually the first solution is the better one. You simply have to find a way to `Replace` the `=Hyperlink` with `=Lien_Hypertexte`. It can be done by any programming language - open the csv, use the replace option and close it.

Answer (score 0):

You could programmatically determine the system language and then use the appropriate functions.

One way would be to retrieve the exact language of Excel (since multiple language packs can be installed) by (within Excel) retrieving the value of:

```
Application.LanguageSettings.LanguageID(msoLanguageIDUI)
```

...for example, English is 1033.

Or, you could retrieve the Windows **`LCID`** (a few ways).

Important related links:

- R : [Query or Set Aspects of the Locale](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/locales.html)
- Ron de Bruin : [Excel version and Office language settings](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win012.htm)
- MrExcel : [Return the language name from an language code](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/617870-language-code-french-spanish-spanish-post3063362.html#post3063362)
- MSDN : [[MS-LCID]: Windows Language Code Identifier (LCID) Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc233965.aspx)
- Stack Overflow : [Excel: Find the current system language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588728/find-the-current-user-language)
- MSDN : [LanguageSettings.LanguageID Property (Office)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/office-shared-vba/articles/languagesettings-languageid-property-office)

Edit:

I'm not sure whether this add-in would be of any use but I figured I'll pass it along too.

> **Multilingual Formula Translator Addin**
>
> A localized Excel addin that translates formulas and functions in several languages.  You have an French version of Excel and your colleague or friend has Dutch?
>   No more problems with this elegant & simple auto-detecting add-in.
>
> <sub>Currently supports 12 languages: (English, Dutch, German, French, Italian, Spanish, Portuguese, Danish, Swedish, Norwegian, Finnish and Russian). Supports 99,9% of all Excel Functions and (macro) commands, including those of the Analysis Toolpak.</sub>

It's hasn't been updated since 2005 so it might be outdated but you can check it out at the [**source** here](http://members.chello.nl/jvolk/keepitcool/addins.html).

Comment: That would not be practical I think as I'm building the csv on my side and pushing it to my user, they are not the one making it.  For the add-in, that looks very interesting and useful for a bilingual organisation.  However I do not have enough IT privileges to install that on my colleagues' machine! Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Bastien - what about the `R` link above, to retrieve the Windows ID locally?

Comment: I may not understand your proposition correctly, but the way I see it, is that I'm building the excel file on my computer (for which I know the language, french) and then saving the file on my company network so my colleagues, all having different languages, can open the file.  Having thing for them to program on their side isn't practical.